# Text classification using POS taggers of spacy

Tags: nlp, spacy, text-classification, pos-tagger

I'm very new to NLP and new to spacy as well and trying to learn things by myself.
My question is, is there a way to classify if a text is sarcastic or if it's a warning or an order, using spacy's pos taggers which are already there to use? For example "Open that door" is an order, how to classify it?

My end goal is I want to classify tweets so I can do more practice and advance a little bit, but for starters I just want to learn how to classify simple sentences.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ is more appropriate for design questions, SO is for programming questions. In short: POS tags can give some indication about predicting orders for example, but even this would not work very well in general. Predicting sarcasm is extremely challenging: it's an active area of research, which means it's not solved even with very complex models. it's certainly not doable only from POS tags.

Comment: Yes, sarcasm is very tough to recognize but it was just an example, how about if an order is given, like I have mentioned in the question, for example "Give me some tea" or something similar, how can we recognize that this is an order? If it can't be done by just using POS tags are there some spacy libraries I can use to classify whether the text is an order or not? I am asking these questions for programming purpose not for design purpose.

Comment: An order usually has the verb first, so if the first POS tag is a verb then the sentence is more likely to be an order. Afaik in general no, there are no library to classify sentences for complex semantic tasks like this. You might find research code repositories which do this kind of thing.

Comment: Oh! thanks, so by just using POS taggers is a poor way of classifying the text which will not generate very accurate outcome if new text is introduced, like if the first word is not a verb but the sentence could be an order, is this correct?

Comment: yes, correct. for a good classifier you would probably need a ML clasisfication model with more features.